# Add values in column based on another column

Tags: r

From

```
x <- read.csv("stats.csv", header = TRUE)
```

I have two columns:

```
Gender   Score
male     20
female   25
male     10
female   10
```

How do I add the total Score for just males for example?

Comment: What's the output you want, just the sum of male values?

Comment: @camille Yes. Using the specified source, I need to just calculate the sum of male scores.

Comment: So just filter/subset your data for just males, then sum score, unless there's something more complicated? Which is why seeing the output you want would be helpful

Comment: @camille the question I guess would be how to filter that subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)     
x %>%
      mutate(totalScore = sum(Score[Gender == "male"]))
```

If the 'female' should be kept as `NA`

```
 x %>%
      mutate(totalScore  = case_when(Gender == "male" ~ sum(Score),
         TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

For both 'Gender'

```
 x %>%
    group_by(Gender) %>%
    mutate(totalScore = sum(Score))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
x['totalScore'] <- with(x, sum(Score[Gender == "male"]))
```

Or to selectively add for the rows

```
i1 <- x$Gender == "male"
x['totalScore'][i1] <- sum(x$Score[i1])
```

Comment: How would this work using the source xx <- read.csv... I just added it

Comment: @PhilK Just replace the `'df1' with 'x'